# Return HLOOKUP value for whole sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have Sheet2 with multiple item (with bold) that contain multiple values.

[image: Sheet2]

In Sheet1 (below) I need to return those value using this formula for B2:

> =IF(A2=0,,HLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!1:1048576,RIGHT(B$1,2)+1,0))

and for C2

> =IF(B2=0,,HLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!1:1048576,RIGHT(C$1,2)+1,0))

FOR B6

> =IF(A6=0,,HLOOKUP($A6,Sheet2!1:1048576,RIGHT(B$1,2)+1,0))

[image: Sheet1]

But, as you can see, it only return first 'line' of table (A,B,C,D), and not table below (E,F,G,H)  I think its very simple changes, but, I still can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your sample data does not accurately represent the actual data set so a transposed [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) could replace your [HLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-f3f3b210-5dd6-4b58-9c83-b9db2c306d6a).

Sample Sheet2:

```
group A group B group C group D
A-001   B-001   C-001   D-001
A-002   B-002   C-002   D-002
A-003   B-003   C-003   D-003
A-004   B-004   C-004   D-004
A-005   B-005   C-005   D-005
        B-006   C-006   D-006
        B-007   C-007   
                C-008   
                C-009   

group E group F group G group H
E-001   F-001   G-001   H-001
E-002   F-002   G-002   H-002
        F-003
```

Sheet1!B2 formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$D, COLUMN(B:B)+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*11, MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 4)+1)&TEXT(,)
```

Copy or fill both right and down. The [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) resolviong to a zero-length string stops INDEX from returning a zero when it encounters a blank cell. The [INT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INT-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef)/[MOD](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-D64C47F3-AAFD-4B2E-AE5D-C16EE3180576)/[ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D)/[COLUMN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COLUMN-function-44E8C754-711C-4DF3-9DA4-47A55042554B) functions are simple mathematical manipulation to resolve a row and column number for INDEX.

[image]

Comment: This is Gold! Even though I still trying to figure it out, why ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*11 and &TEXT(,). Where can I further study this? for more details, link provided not much info. Very thankful for your help.

Comment: I really want to study more on this. Can you kindly give some books, or reference to dig further?

Comment: `TEXT(,)` is just another way to resolve a zero-length string; e.g. `""`. Put `=INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*11` into an unused cell and fill down and right to see how it adjusts the row number returned to the INDEX function. Btw, if the data in Sheet2 changes often, you may want to use `INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)*Sheet2!ROW(11:11)` to auto-compensate for inserted or deleted rows to offset. Check all of the links I provided in my answer for official support.office.com docs.

Comment: Thank you. But, is it possible to use LOOKUP function? or other function, because, this formula is static. Meaning, when for example I change A7 row into group H instead if F, data in column B,C,D,.. didn't change.

Comment: Yes, you could make the formula into a lookup but you would have to use IFERROR to cycle through each of four columns.